# Skip invalid elements in a sequence with Serde deserialization

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

Using Serde, I would like to Deserialize a sequence of elements by keeping the valid elements and skip the invalid ones.

I have the following payload:

```
{
    "nhits": 30,
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "occupation-parkings-temps-reel",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "rows": 50,
        "start": 0,
        "format": "json",
        "facet": [
            "etat_descriptif"
        ]
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "datasetid": "occupation-parkings-temps-reel",
            "recordid": "1436c55a76fc7910b5a0336eb74cc0957870a8fd",
            "fields": {
                "nom_parking": "P1 Esplanade - Centre commercial",
                "etat": 1,
                "ident": 27,
                "infousager": "220",
                "idsurfs": "1703_DEP_27",
                "libre": 229,
                "total": 251,
                "etat_descriptif": "Ouvert"
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2020-12-20T12:51:00.704000+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "occupation-parkings-temps-reel",
            "recordid": "2b15689c04478fcad8c964a5d9f3c0148eb70126",
            "fields": {
                "etat": 1,
                "ident": 30,
                "infousager": "LIBRE",
                "libre": 719,
                "total": 719,
                "etat_descriptif": "Ouvert"
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2020-12-20T12:51:00.704000+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "facet_groups": [
        {
            "facets": [
                {
                    "count": 28,
                    "path": "Ouvert",
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "name": "Ouvert"
                },
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "path": "Ferm\u00e9",
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "name": "Ferm\u00e9"
                },
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "path": "frequentation temps reel indisponible",
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "name": "frequentation temps reel indisponible"
                }
            ],
            "name": "etat_descriptif"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a different strucs that correspond:

```
/// The container for the API response
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct OpenDataResponse<T> {
    /// The parameters relative to the response
    pub parameters: Parameters,

    /// The parameters relative to the pagination
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub pagination: Pagination,

    /// The sets of records inside the response
    #[serde(bound(deserialize = "T: Deserialize<'de>"))]
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize::failable_records")]
    pub records: Vec<Record<T>>,
}

/// A record represents an item of some data
/// with a specific id.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Record<T> {
    /// The identifier of the record
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "recordid"))]
    pub id: String,

    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "fields"))]
    pub(crate) inner: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct StatusOpenData {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "idsurfs"))]
    pub id: String,

    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "nom_parking"))]
    pub name: String,

    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "etat"))]
    pub status: i8,

    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "libre"))]
    pub free: u16,

    pub total: u16,

    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "etat_descriptif"))]
    pub users_info: Option<String>,
}
```

In regards to those definitions, a `StatusOpenData` element has some required fields. So in the
the `records` from the example, the first element is valid and the second is invalid.

I implemented my own deserialization method `deserialize::failable_records` as:

```
struct FailableDeserialize<T> {
    inner: Option<T>,
}

impl<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>> Deserialize<'de> for FailableDeserialize<T> {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let value: Option<T> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer).ok();
        Ok(FailableDeserialize { inner: value })
    }
}

pub(super) fn failable_records<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    // Error returned from the line below
    let elements: Vec<FailableDeserialize<T>> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    let result = elements.into_iter().filter_map(|f| f.inner).collect();
    Ok(result)
}
```

This failed with some error like: `should take errors into account: Error("expected` ,`or`]`",`

I do not understand why the error is returned:
`let elements: Vec<FailableDeserialize<T>> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;` tries do deserialize a sequence of `FailableDeserialize<T>` elements but this type implements a `Deserialize` in a way he can not return an error.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put together a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) example of the failure?

Comment: [`serde_with::DefaultONError`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/3.4.0/serde_with/struct.DefaultOnError.html) might be useful for you to accept invalid JSON data here.

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward approach of ignoring an error with `ok()` will lead to a desynchronization of the deserializer.
The deserialization error can happen on any token and does not need to happen only after a full element is consumed.
If deserializing a `Record` fails serde will be stuck inside the `Record` object, but the `Vec` deserializer expects a `,` which it will not find.

It is easier if you stick to existing crates which already provide something like your `FailableDeserialize`.
You can use [`serde_with::DefaultOnError`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.6.4/serde_with/struct.DefaultOnError.html) to write `failable_records` like this:

```rust
fn failable_records<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    #[serde_with::serde_as]
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(bound(deserialize = "T: Deserialize<'de>"))]
    struct Wrapper<T>(#[serde_as(deserialize_as = "Vec<serde_with::DefaultOnError>")] Vec<Option<T>>);

    // Error returned from the line below
    let elements: Wrapper<T> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    let result = elements.0.into_iter().filter_map(|f| f).collect();
    Ok(result)
}
```

Internally it uses an untagged enum to work around the desynchronization problem, since that will consume one full object before starting the real deserialization.