# Skip empty or faulty rows with Serde

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I have a file with valid rows that I'm parsing to a struct using Serde and the csv crate.

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Circle {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    radius: f32,
}

fn read_csv(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<Circle>, csv::Error> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new().delimiter(b';').from_path(path)?;

    let res: Vec<Circle> = rdr
        .deserialize()
        .map(|record: Result<Circle, csv::Error>| {
            record.unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("There was a problem parsing a row: {}", err))
        })
        .collect();

    Ok(res)
}
```

This code work for the most times, but sometimes when I get files they contain "empty" rows at the end:

```
x;y;radius
6398921.770;146523.553;0.13258
6398921.294;146522.452;0.13258
6398914.106;146526.867;0.13258
;;;
```

This makes the parsing fail with

> thread 'main' panicked at 'There was a problem parsing a row: CSV
> deserialize error: record 4 (line: 4, byte: 194): field 0: cannot
> parse float from empty string', src/main.rs:90:41 note: run with
> `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

How can I handle faulty rows without manipulating the file contents beforehand?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip invalid elements in a sequence with Serde deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390458/skip-invalid-elements-in-a-sequence-with-serde-deserialization)

Comment: The panic results from your code. To handle the deserialization error, you replace the `unwrap_or_else` with the handling code. What kind of handling do you have in mind? Simply skip the entries, use a defaulted Circle, or do you want to collect all errors?

Comment: @jonasbb collecting all errors sound like a good solution. How can I do that?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/iter_result.html